# ListView binding working out of the box, whereas custom implementation not?

Tags: wpf, listview, data-binding

I came back to an old project and wanted to update some code. I had this implementation that was working nicely:

```
<ListView
         Background="{StaticResource  WindowBackgroundColorBrush}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfProjects}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProject, Mode=TwoWay}">
</ListView>
```

I decided to rewrite it as collection of buttons for a reason, so I changed the above to:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfProjects}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Style="{ StaticResource ProjectListButtonStyle}" Content="{Binding Name}"                                    
                    Command="{Binding ElementName=ContainerContent, Path=DataContext.ProjectSelectedCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ID}"
            />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>                                
</ItemsControl>
```

I created a `ProjectSelectedCommand` command which was simply implemented as:

```
this.ProjectSelectedCommand = new RelayCommand(x => this.OnProjectsSelected((int)x));

public void OnProjectsSelected(int projectID)
{
    this.SelectedProject = this.ListOfProjects.Where(x => x.ID == projectID).First();
}
```

But as a result the binding does not work. I have a simple textblock to display the name of the project:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SelectedProject.Name}"></TextBlock>
```

With the first implementation the project name changes, but with the second (with the buttons and the command) it does not when I click the project button. I can see that the debugger goes into the command and in the ViewModel I can see the `SelectedProject` changing, but the view does not update it. Anyone any idea what may be the issue behind the second implementation?

Comment: Try posting your VM code, it sounds like a problem with your INPC.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I found the issue - going to add an answer with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it seems the issue was the binding in the button. I used `ElementName` and referenced the dynamic content container that I have in my WPF application for changing ViewModel views. To fix this I just added a general `FindAncestor` and now it seems to work:

```
<Button Style="{ StaticResource ProjectListButtonStyle}"
    Content="{Binding Name}"                                    
    Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ProjectSelectedCommand,
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding}"
/>
```

The strange thing is that earlier I saw it going into the `OnProjectSelected` method, but the view didn't receive the notification. Maybe there was an issue with the context of ElementName as in my case it changes during runtime. Anyway, seems like the above fixes the issue.